# How do I get git to ignore my build directory on every branch other than master?

Tags: git

I have a build directory that I want to check in to git so that other people with access to the project can just run it without having to do a build.  This directory is causing issues with my workflow, however, as there is a monitoring script that constantly rebuilds files in it.

So the gist of what happens:

- on master
- `git checkout some_branch`
- a bunch of files in *`/build`* get changed automatically
- `git checkout master`

  *Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.*
- gah, `git checkout -- build`

So basically I'm trying to figure out a way to have the build directory ignored from every branch other than master.  Or maybe I just want to ignore *all* conflicts in the build directory since the files immediately get replaced anyway.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have three choices;

- Disable the script that changes the files
- Add the files that are changed to `.gitignore`
- Make sure that the changes can be caught by the smudge/clean filters of `.gitattibutes`.